# get token from more 1 type by javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 4 type of url and need to get token.

```
type1 http://gettoken/index.php?action=test&token=aaaaa

type2 http://gettoken/index.php?action=test&token=aaaaa&login=admin

type3 http://gettoken/index.phpaction=test&login=admin&token=aaaaa&expires=3600

type4 http://gettoken/index.php?action=test&login=admin&expires=3600&token=aaaaa
```

and token length 5 character.

Comment: And your problem is...?

Comment: Please improve your question by include what it is you have tried and what went wrong. Also, it needs a question. Voting to close this until it's better.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters

Comment: Dupplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the function which will return any parameter value from url

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
if (!url) url = window.location.href;
name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
if (!results) return null;
if (!results[2]) return '';
return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

**Use it like bellow**

```
var url ="http://gettoken/index.php?action=test&login=admin&token=aaaaa&expires=3600";
var action = getParameterByName('action',url); // "test"
var login = getParameterByName('login',url); // "admin"
var token = getParameterByName('token',url); // "aaaaa"
```

Comment: Copy pasted from there: https://stackoverflow.com/q/901115/#answer-901144 should have reported the question as duplicate instead.

Comment: Mark question as duplicated. I can't do see my reputation score.